# How to run a single Dart file in your Flutter project using Android Studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, configuration, program-entry-point

**Is there a way to run a single file with a main function without having to compile the entire app?**

I want to be able to test snippets of code, even when the projects as a whole is not compiling.

I have created a `main_scraps.dart` file with a `main()` method in it and target this file when running, but since it compiles the entire project it will never run.

**Can I run one file in a project or should I use dartpad or a new project to do so?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, there is a file for data seeding and it is run on-demand in the terminal, independently and isolated from the `main()` function of the entire Flutter app:

```dart
/// This file is at lib/seeding/seed_services.service.dart  
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:users/services/gmp_service/find_nearby_places.service.dart';

seedServices() async {
  print(jsonEncode(await findNearbyPlaces()));
}

// Any dart program must have a main() function.
main() {
  seedServices();
}
```

In the command line, run the following command to execute the file:

```bash
dart lib/seeding/seed_services.service.dart
```

U can have multiple independent files in the same root directory of a Flutter project to seed different data, each file with its own `main()` function. Flutter already uses this technique for unit test (u can check the test folder), each test file has its own `main()` function.